# Create a deep nested hash using loops in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a nested hash using four values `type`, `name`, `year`, `value`. ie, key of the first hash will be `type`, value will be another hash with key `name`, then value of that one will be another hash with key `year` and value as `value`.

The array of objects I'm iterating looks like this:

```rb
elements = [
    {
        year: '2018',
        items: [
            {
                name: 'name1',
                value: 'value1',
                type: 'type1',
            },
            {
                name: 'name2',
                value: 'value2',
                type: 'type2',
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        year: '2019',
        items: [
            {
                name: 'name3',
                value: 'value3',
                type: 'type2',
            },
            {
                name: 'name4',
                value: 'value4',
                type: 'type1',
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

And I'm getting all values together using two loops like this:

```rb
elements.each do |element|
    year = element.year
    element.items.each |item|
        name = item.name
        value = item.value
        type = item.type

        # TODO: create nested hash
    end
end
```

Expected output is like this:

```rb
{
    "type1" => {
        "name1" => {
            "2018" => "value1"
        },
        "name4" => {
            "2019" => "value4"
        }
    },
    "type2" => {
        "name2" => {
            "2018" => "value2"
        },
        "name3" => {
            "2019" => "value3"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried out some methods but it doesn't seems to work out as expected. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please add your tried solutions

Comment: Your JSON is malformed.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin actually it is an array of objects, just corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to preserve the references (unlike in your desired output,) here you go:

```
elements = [
  {
    year: '2018',
    items: [
      {name: 'name1', value: 'value1', type: 'type1'},
      {name: 'name2', value: 'value2', type: 'type2'}
    ]
},
{
    year: '2019',
    items: [
      {name: 'name3', value: 'value3', type: 'type2'},
      {name: 'name4', value: 'value4', type: 'type1'}
    ]
  }
]
```

Just iterate over everything and reduce into the hash. On the structures of known shape is’s a trivial task:

```
elements.each_with_object(
    Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) } # for deep bury
) do |h, acc|
  h[:items].each do |item|
    acc[item[:type]][item[:name]][h[:year]] = item[:value]
  end
end

#⇒ {"type1"=>{"name1"=>{"2018"=>"value1"},
#             "name4"=>{"2019"=>"value4"}},
#   "type2"=>{"name2"=>{"2018"=>"value2"},
#             "name3"=>{"2019"=>"value3"}}}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
elements.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| g[:items].each { |f|
    h.update(f[:type]=>{ f[:name]=>{ g[:year]=>f[:value] } }) { |_,o,n| o.merge(n) } } }
  #=> {"type1"=>{"name1"=>{"2018"=>"value1"}, "name4"=>{"2019"=>"value4"}},
  #    "type2"=>{"name2"=>{"2018"=>"value2"}, "name3"=>{"2019"=>"value3"}}}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block (here `{ |_,o,n| o.merge(n) }` to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for definitions of the three block variables (here `_`, `o` and `n`). Note that in performing `o.merge(n)` `o` and `n` will have no common keys, so a block is not needed for that operation.

Comment: Good one! I wonder when will we have `Hash#bury` or like to avoid this ugly fence `{=>{=>{=>{=>` :)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: `class Hash; def bury(*keys, val); keys.size > 1 ? self.dig(*keys[0..-2])[keys[-1]] = val : self[keys.first] = val; end; end` (the hash better be autovivifying, though, or it won't be too useful),